# Question about equivalencies when using the existential quantifier

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, quantifiers

I'm currently in a boolean algebra class, and we are asked if the statement:

$$
\exists xM(x) \wedge \exists xD(x) 
$$

is a proposition. Although I know that it is a proposition, I was wondering if anyone knew if it could be simplified to

$$
\exists x (M(x) \wedge D(x))
$$

Since I know that this is true at least:

$$
\forall x(M(x) \wedge D(x)) \equiv \forall x M(x) \wedge \forall x D(x)
$$

Comment: A rule you can use is : $$\exists x~\bigg(M(x) \color{red}{\lor} D(x)\bigg)\quad \equiv \quad \bigg(\exists x ~M(x)\bigg) \color{red}{\lor} \bigg(\exists x ~D(x)\bigg)$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps let $M$ be "Man who likes cookies." Let $D$ be "Woman who likes dogs."

The first statement 
$$
\exists xM(x) \wedge \exists xD(x) 
$$
means that there is a man who likes cookies (Me) and there is a woman who likes dogs (My wife).

But, the second statement
$$
\exists x(M(x) \wedge D(x)) 
$$
 means "There exists a person that is **both** a man who likes cookies and a woman that likes dogs." Less likely. The two statements are not equivalent.